# d3 with angular2 with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.17

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular-cli

I'm having issues using D3 with my angular2 project. I keep getting errors such as 'time is not defined' or 'time is not a property of typeof D3'.

I installed d3 via npm and installed the typings for it: `npm install d3 --save`. 
In my component I have `import * as d3 from 'd3';` and it's able to find the library fine.

I have tried adding 
   `"addons": [{ "d3" : "vendor/d3/build/d3.js"}], packages": [{ "d3" : "vendor/d3/build/d3.js"}],`
in the angular-cli.json. Neither work.

package.json includes the following dev dependencies: 
 
    `"devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3-array": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-axis": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-brush": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-chord": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-collection": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-color": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-dispatch": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-drag": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-dsv": "^1.0.29",
    "@types/d3-ease": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-force": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-format": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-geo": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/d3-hierarchy": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-hsv": "0.0.3",
    "@types/d3-interpolate": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/d3-path": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-polygon": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-quadtree": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-queue": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/d3-random": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-request": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/d3-scale": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-scale-chromatic": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/d3-selection": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-selection-multi": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-time": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-time-format": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/d3-timer": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-transition": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-voronoi": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/d3-zoom": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",`

dependencies: 
    `"@types/d3": "^4.2.38", "d3": "^4.3.0",`

I'm using this example: http://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/gkHwJ in my app. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are using as a base is referencing D3 v3 from `http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`, while your app is using D3 v4, which has breaking changes in API.

`d3.time` does not exist anymore, so you'll have to adapt the code to the new API. For example, the line 82, in the Codepen example you link:

```
var parse = d3.time.format( '%Y-%m-%d' );
```

Has to be converted to:

```
var parse = d3.timeFormat( '%Y-%m-%d' );
```

As you can see from the [module export](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/index.js#L306) on the main D3 repo `index.js` or in the relevant readme of the [d3 time format module](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format).

Rinse and repeat for each outdated syntax (`d3.scale.linear` is now `d3.scaleLinear` for example), keeping the above [index.js](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/index.js) file as a reference and I think you will get rid of all the errors.

Comment: I was also missing the d3.d.ts file I guess. And the following line in the tsd.json file: ` "d3/d3.d.ts": {"commit":"84dfeeac378552c22297a5d555b1999a396d7e7c"}`